# Speed up sentence processing by BERT in Transformers

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have this code:

```py
import torch
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

model = 'bert-base-uncased' 
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model)
Sentence_vectorList = []
for sent in x_train:

  input_sentence = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(sent)).unsqueeze(0)
  out = model(input_sentence)
  embeddings_of_last_layer = out[0]
  cls_embeddings = embeddings_of_last_layer[0]

  cls_layer = cls_embeddings.detach().numpy()

  sent_emd = np.average(cls_layer,axis=0)
```

The task is to take the sentence vectors and detach them in [n x 768] then I save them as sent2vec. This process is taking a lot of time. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can get some small speedup by processing the sentences in batches. A batch size of 100 might be a reasonable choice. When processing the sentences in batches, the model needs to be aware of how long each sentence in the batch is. The [`batch_encode_plus`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html?highlight=batch_encode_plus#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.batch_encode_plus) of the tokenizer takes care of that. Note that the method returns a dictionary, so you need to pass the output to the models as:

```py
out = model(**input_sentences)
```

The variable `out` will contain vectors for all sentences in the batch.

The speedup of processing the sentences in batches is relatively small on CPU, but pretty big on GPU. Transformers are pretty large models and they will be slow on CPU no matter what you do. If you are fine with a lower quality of the vectors, you can try smaller transformers such as DistilBERT.

Comment: Just as a quick addendum that such large batch sizes are quite hard to realize on GPUs. Realistically, most consumer-grade GPUs can fit batches of <16 samples at the same time. However, especially during inference or when processing on CPUs, I completely agree!

Answer (score 0):

We have opened a pull request with Intel OpenVINO backend: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/14203. Maybe you can be interested in using it on CPU.